# Why this C++ fancy swap() doesn't work in Java

Tags: java, c++

I recently read about the XOR way to do swap():

```
void swap1(int[] arr, int a, int b) {
    arr[a] = arr[a] ^ arr[b];
    arr[b] = arr[a] ^ arr[b];
    arr[a] = arr[a] ^ arr[b];
}
```

Making it shorter, we have:

```
void swap2(int[] arr, int a, int b) {
    arr[a] ^= arr[b] ^ (arr[b] = arr[a]);
}
```

And:

```
void swap3(int arr[], int a, int b) {
    arr[a] ^= arr[b] ^= arr[a] ^= arr[b];
}
```

However, `swap3()` only works in C++ and doesn't work on Java after migrated. What difference between C++ and Java makes the same code provide different results when compiled in different language?

Comment: _"doesn't work "_ -- explain what you mean by this

Comment: a) C++ is not Java. Is that enough reason?

Comment: swap2 is undefined behavior in C++

Comment: (and Swap3 is too)